# PF4J throws "Plugin-Version cannot be empty"

Tags: java, semantic-versioning, pf4j

I set up a PF4J plugin as described on the [github readme](https://github.com/decebals/pf4j), but without using maven.

I get the following error:

```
[main] ERROR ro.fortsoft.pf4j.DefaultPluginManager - Plugin-Version cannot be empty
ro.fortsoft.pf4j.PluginException: Plugin-Version cannot be empty
at ro.fortsoft.pf4j.ManifestPluginDescriptorFinder.validatePluginDescriptor(ManifestPluginDescriptorFinder.java:135)
at ro.fortsoft.pf4j.ManifestPluginDescriptorFinder.find(ManifestPluginDescriptorFinder.java:50)
at ro.fortsoft.pf4j.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDirectory(DefaultPluginManager.java:804)
at ro.fortsoft.pf4j.DefaultPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultPluginManager.java:400)
at ...
```

but my MANIFEST.MF obviously contains a Plugin-Version:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: myname
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Plugin-Class: my.first.WelcomePlugin
Plugin-Id: welcome-plugin
Plugin-Provider: providername
Plugin-Version: 0.0.1
```

I also added Java SemVer v0.9.0

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE:** I put the Plugin-Version line on top of the manifest file and now it seems to work ..

Comment: So you can you answer your own question?  Please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the Plugin-Version line on top of the manifest file and now it seems to work:

```
Plugin-Version: 0.0.1
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: myname
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Plugin-Class: my.first.WelcomePlugin
Plugin-Id: welcome-plugin
Plugin-Provider: providername
```